# select only ".apk" file from file manager android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am developing a app in which i want to show only apk files to user so he could select only .apk files from file manager. I found several answers but rest didnt work for me. i tried  intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive" Infact i am unable to restrict user even only to images. 
here is my code

```
  private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //sets the select file to all types of files
    intent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    //allows to select data and return it
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //starts new activity to select file and return data
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File to Upload.."), PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "didnt work for me" means.

Comment: means i tried some solutions but didnt succeeded to solve my problem. I only want that the user can select only apk files from file manager.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "didnt succeeded to solve my problem" means. Nobody can help you unless you explain, **in detail**, what the problem is. For example, are you crashing? If so, examine LogCat and look at the Java stack trace associated with your crash.